# Invalid block type: Code is working fine locally but after uploading to live enterprise site, it is giving error

Tags: magento-enterprise, blocks, exception

I am new to magento. I followed one tutorial and created one custom report. Report is working fine on local pc but after i deployed the report on live server it is not giving any error and showing blank page. Exception.log is showing the below trace

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type:     Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Mymodule' in /var/www/xxxx.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php:595
```

app\code\local\Mycompany\Mymodule\etc\config.xml

```
 */
 -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Mymodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mycompany_Mymodule</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <report>
                <children>
                    <mymodule translate="title" module="mymodule">
                        <title>Order Fullfillment Report</title>
                        <action>mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule</action>
                    </mymodule>
                </children>
            </report>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <report>
                            <children>
                                <mymodule translate="title" module="mymodule">
                                    <title>Mymodule Report</title>
                                    <action>mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule</action>
                                </mymodule>
                            </children>
                        </report>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mymodule</resourceModel>
            </mymodule>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <mymodule_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mycompany_Mymodule</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_setup>
            <mymodule_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_write>
            <mymodule_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Helper</class>
            </mymodule>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

\app\etc\modules\Mycompany_Mymodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Mymodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mycompany_Mymodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\mymodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <mymodule_adminhtml_mymodule_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule" name="mymodule" />
        </reference>
    </mymodule_adminhtml_mymodule_index>
</layout>
```

app\code\local\Mycompany\Mymodule\Model\Mymodule.php

```
<?php
    class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Mymodule extends Mage_Reports_Model_Mysql4_Order_Collection
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setResourceModel('sales/order_item');
        $this->_init('sales/order_item','item_id');
   }

    public function setDateRange($from, $to) {
        $this->_reset();
       $this->getSelect()->reset()
       ->from(
         array('sf' => 'V_Order_Fullfillment_Report2'),
            array(
                '1DayC' => '(sum(sf.1DayC))',
                 '1DayP' => '(sum(sf.1DayP))',
                  '2DayC' => '(sum(sf.2DayC))',
                   '2DayP' => '(sum(sf.2DayP))',
                    '3DayC' => '(sum(sf.3DayC))',
                     '3DayP' => '(sum(sf.3DayP))',
                      '4DayC' => '(sum(sf.4DayC))',
                       '4DayP' => '(sum(sf.4DayP))',
                        '5DayC' => '(sum(sf.5DayC))',
                         '5DayP' => '(sum(sf.5DayP))',
                          '5pDayC' => '(sum(sf.5pDayC))',
                           '5pDayP' => '(sum(sf.5pDayP))',
                'New_Orders' => '(count(sf.increment_id))' 
            ))
        ->where("sf.created_at BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'")

       ;

        // uncomment next line to get the query log:
        //  Mage::log('SQL: '.$this->getSelect()->__toString());
        return $this;
    }

    public function setStoreIds($storeIds)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    }
    ?>
```

app\code\local\Mycompany\Mymodule\Block\adminhtml\Mymodule\Grid.php

```
<?php
 class Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Mymodule_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('mymoduleGrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
    $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setSubReportSize(false);
}


protected function _prepareCollection() {
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    $this->getCollection()->initReport('mymodule/mymodule');
    return $this;
}

protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $this->addColumn('New_Orders', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('New Orders'),
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'New_Orders',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));
     $this->addColumn('1DayC', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('1Day Complete'),
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'1DayC',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));
     $this->addColumn('1DayP', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('1Day Partial'),
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'1DayP',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));
     $this->addColumn('2DayC', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('2Day Complete'),
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'2DayC',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));
     $this->addColumn('2DayP', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('2Day Partial'),
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'2DayP',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));
     $this->addColumn('3DayC', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('3Day Complete'),
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'3DayC',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));
     $this->addColumn('3DayP', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('3Day Partial'),
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'3DayP',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));
     $this->addColumn('4DayC', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('4Day Complete'),
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'4DayC',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));
     $this->addColumn('4DayP', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('4Day Partial'),
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'4DayP',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));
     $this->addColumn('5DayC', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('5Day Complete'),
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'5DayC',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));
     $this->addColumn('5DayP', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('5Day Partial'),
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'5DayP',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));
     $this->addColumn('5pDayC', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('5+Day Complete'),
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'5pDayC',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));
     $this->addColumn('5pDayP', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('5+Day Partial'),
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'5pDayP',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('XML'));
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

public function getRowUrl($row) {
    return false;
}

public function getReport($from, $to) {
    if ($from == '') {
        $from = $this->getFilter('report_from');
    }
    if ($to == '') {
        $to = $this->getFilter('report_to');
    }
    $totalObj = Mage::getModel('reports/totals');
    $totals = $totalObj->countTotals($this, $from, $to);
    $this->setTotals($totals);
    $this->addGrandTotals($totals);

    return $this->getCollection()->getReport($from, $to);
}
}
```

app\code\local\Mycompany\Mymodule\Block\adminhtml\Mymodule.php

```
<?php
 class Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Mymodule extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container {


public function __construct() {
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_mymodule';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'mymodule';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Order Fullfillment Report');
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_removeButton('add');
}
}
```

app\code\local\Mycompany\Mymodule\Block\Mymodule.php

```
<?php
 class Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Mymodule extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

public function _prepareLayout() {
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

public function getMymodule() {
    if (!$this->hasData('mymodule')) {
        $this->setData('mymodule', Mage::registry('mymodule'));
    }
    return $this->getData('mymodule');
} 
}
```

app\code\local\Mycompany\Mymodule\controllers\Adminhtml\MymoduleController.php

```
<?php

 class Mycompany_Mymodule_Adminhtml_MymoduleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

protected function _initAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    return $this;
}

public function indexAction() {
    $this->_initAction()
            ->renderLayout();
}

public function exportCsvAction() {
    $fileName = 'mymodule.csv';
    $content = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_grid')
                    ->getCsv();
    $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);
}

public function exportXmlAction() {
    $fileName = 'mymodule.xml';
    $content = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_grid')
                    ->getXml();
    $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);
}

protected function _sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType='application/octet-stream') {
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setHeader('HTTP/1.1 200 OK', '');
    $response->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true);
    $response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true);
    $response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $fileName);
    $response->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r'));
    $response->setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
    $response->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($content));
    $response->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType);
    $response->setBody($content);
    $response->sendResponse();
    die;
}
}
```

Comment: check if all files for this module are on your live server (module declaration / config.xml etc). Try cleaning cache again.

Comment: Check also file permission

Comment: I cleaned cache Mutiple times. have done the file/folder permissions but problems remains the same. I copied the app folder as it as from local to live server and then copied layout file to app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\mymodule.xml and copied the last file to app\etc\modules\Mycompany_Mymodule.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you did not define your blocks type as `Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Mymodule` in your layout.xml the error Message is saying that your Module and also the layout updates do work basically.

Would still be helpful if you could post the xml where you add the block in the layout

For some reason the class cannot be loaded by the autoloader. This can be due to a typo in the Class Name, File Name, layout.xml or Directory.

another reason would be if you don't have the block directive in your config.xml under global.

Comment: app\etc\modules\Mycompany_Mymodule.xml <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Mymodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mycompany_Mymodule>
    </modules>
</config>

Comment: layout file --- <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <mymodule_adminhtml_mymodule_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule" name="mymodule" />
        </reference>
    </mymodule_adminhtml_mymodule_index>
</layout>

Comment: I copied the working folder from local system to live server without editing anything so chance of typo are close to 0.

Comment: in your etc/config.xml do you have the following part? (it's important so that magento can locate your block classes) https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml#L428

Comment: yes.. please find below my config.xml (Thank you for your help ) <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Helper</class>
            </mymodule>
        </helpers>
    </global>

Comment: ok, your config seems to be right. knowing this, the error message says, it either can't locate your file (which should be located at app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Mymodule.php) or it could not find the classname in it which should be Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Mymodule or it is not extending the Mage_Core_Block_Abstract class. This information is from here: https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php#L482. you could actually add some debug code for testing purposes here

Comment: Thank you, i will look into this. i have also updated the question with all code files, please have a look there as well. Please note that code is working fine locally..

Comment: in your comment above you wrote the path app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Mymodule.php with "A" capital for Adminhtml but i have folder name adminhtml.. can this be a problem... but i still wonder how can this work on local system.. will give it a try now..

Comment: It worked....  Thank you .. you are my savior...

Comment: The reason for working locally and not on live server could be : my local server is windows which is not case sensitive for folder name but i think my live server is linux which is case sensitive for folder names :)